# Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T: \mathcal{P}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1$ with $T(a + bx) = b - ax$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T: \mathcal{P}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1$ with $T(a + bx) = b - ax$, with bases $B = \{1+x, 1-x\}$ and $C = \{1, x\}$ respectively. Then verify your answer by computing $T(4 + 2x)$

I am not sure where I am going wrong:

$T(\mathbb{e}_1) = T(1+x) = 1 - x$
$T(\mathbb{e}_2) = T(1-x) = -1 - x$

Using the basis $C$:

$1 - x = \mathbb{e}_1 - \mathbb{e}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$
$1 - x = -\mathbb{e}_1 - \mathbb{e}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

So the $T_A$ should be:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}$

However this appears to be incorrect as:

$T(4+2x) = 2 - 4x$

but

$4+2x = -1\mathbb{e}_1 + 3\mathbb{e}_2$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-4\\-2\end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix}2\\-4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $4+2x=3(1+x)+(1-x)=3e_{1}+e_{2}$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Well spotted, thank you.